# OnCollisionEnter2D not working

Tags: unity, collision-detection, rigidbody, collider

I am fairly new to Unity2D and am making a 2D platformer to get used to the engine. I am trying to create a platform that moves when the player jumps on it, however, on the script for the platform the OnCollisionEnter2D method is just not being called. This is the script:

```
public class ThrustPlatform : MonoBehaviour

[SerializeField] float thrustSpeed;
[SerializeField] float thrustDistance;

Animator thrustAnim;
Rigidbody2D rb;

private bool thrust = false;
private Vector2 startPos;
private Vector2 targetPos;


void Start()
{
    thrustAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    startPos = transform.position;
    float targetX = startPos.x + thrustDistance;
    targetPos = new Vector2(targetX, startPos.y);
}


private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
{
    Debug.Log("COLLISION");
    thrust = true;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(thrust)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(thrustSpeed, 0);
    }
}
```

The player and platform are on layers that can collide with each other in the collision matrix, the player still lands on the platform, and the player has a dynamic rigid body and the platform a kinematic rigid body. As far as I am aware kinematic rigid bodies detect collisions from dynamic rigid body, I have watched tutorials where this works. Even if I change the platform rigid body to dynamic there is no detection. I have also tried using continuous collision detection on both rigid bodies but still it is not calling. If I change it to a trigger and use OnTriggerEnter2D however, the Debug line appears.

This is the rigidbody for the platform.
[image: Rigidbody details for the platform]

This is the rigidbody details for the player.
[image: Rigidbody details for the player]

I am very confused as to why this isn't working and I can't find a solution anywhere else (unless I am missing something very obvious).

Comment: Is `IsTrigger` enabled on the Floor? Because if it is OnCollisionEnter doesn't get called, but OnTriggerEnter instead.

Comment: No I only enabled IsTrigger to test if OnTriggerEnter worked, which it did, then changed it back to try OnCollisionEnter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your method signature must match the one given in the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html).

`OnCollisionEnter2D` takes a `Collision2D` argument, not a `Collider2D` argument as you've used here.

Because your signature doesn't match, Unity finds no matching `OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)` function to call, so it doesn't call it.